# Why am I getting NoClassDefFoundError even though I have already included the dependency in the pom.xml?

Tags: maven, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am modifying the Keycloak codebase (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak) to include a use case that I need (decrypt JWE when during Identity Brokering).

To decrypt a JWE, I added a dependency for com.nimbusds.nimbus-jose-jwt:
In the keycloak-parent/pom.xml, I added the dependency and the version

```
<properties>
...
  <nimbus-jose-jwt.version>5.7</nimbus-jose-jwt.version>
...
</properties>
...
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
  ...
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
       <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
       <version>${nimbus-jose-jwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  ...
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In the keycloak-services/pom.xml, I added the dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
  <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I also added a new function called "getDecryptedToken" to keycloak-services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/broker/oidc/OIDCIdentityProvider.java

I then ran this command to build

```
mvn -Pdistribution -pl distribution/server-dist -am -Dmaven.test.skip clean install
```

With this build, I get the following exception when I clicked on the external provider link when clicking on the link to an external identity provider. I am very puzzled as to why this is happening as I have already added the dependency in the keycloak-services/pom.xml.

```
8:32:42,663 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-7) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nimbusds/jose/JOSEException
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProviderFactory.create(OIDCIdentityProviderFactory.java:43)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProviderFactory.create(OIDCIdentityProviderFactory.java:32)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.services.resources.IdentityBrokerService.performLogin(IdentityBrokerService.java:390)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:535)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:424)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:385)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:356)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:150)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:104)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:91)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:370)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException from [Module "org.keycloak.keycloak-services" version 10.0.2 from local module loader @38aa816f (finder: local module finder @53f6fd09 (roots: /Users/dev/Documents/Github/keycloak/keycloak-10.0.2/modules,/Users/dev/Documents/Github/keycloak/keycloak-10.0.2/modules/system/layers/keycloak,/Users/dev/Documents/Github/keycloak/keycloak-10.0.2/modules/system/layers/base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 73 more
```

Comment: Do you have the code in a branch/pull request?

Comment: I forked the code into my own repo https://github.com/Edmund-Loh/keycloak/tree/decrypt_jwe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from the Keycloak community, I have identified that besides updating the pom.xml in the keycloak-parent and services projects, I also had to update the distribution project to include module definitions for the newly added dependency.

In my case I had to update the following module definition to indicate a new dependency

```
distribution/feature-packs/server-feature-pack/src/main/resources/modules/system/layers/keycloak/org/keycloak/keycloak-services/main/module.xml
```

I added nimbus to the existing list of dependencies

```
<dependencies>
...
  <module name="com.nimbusds.nimbus-jose-jwt"/>
</dependencies>
```

I've also had to create a new module definition

```
distribution/feature-packs/server-feature-pack/src/main/resources/modules/system/layers/keycloak/com/nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/main/module.xml
```

This are its contents. I got its dependencies from its own pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.nimbusds.nimbus-jose-jwt">
    <resources>
        <artifact name="${com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt}"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.github.stephenc.jcip.jcip-annotations"/>
        <module name="net.minidev.json-smart"/>
        <module name="org.bouncycastle.bcprov-jdk15on"/>
        <module name="org.bouncycastle.bcpkix-jdk15on"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```